# Finding lowest Value in one dim array using iteration (Can't use max/min)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, iteration

I'm currently taking intro to c# in school.

My instructor has asked me to:

- Determine the lowest value of a one dimensional array using iteration.
- I can't use conventional means such as max or min functions. It has to be done using iteration.
- I'm getting the array values from user input.

  This is what I have below, but I feel like this isn't really what he wants. 
  --EDIT--
  I can't use a maxvalue attribute. That is beyond the scope of what he's taught. For those that are looking for a more specific question.

Without showing me full code examples. How are some other ways I might be able to solve this without the use of minimumvalue or maximumvalue attributes?

I apologize for not being clearer than that. This is only my 3rd week in the course, so my understanding of programming in general is very low.

```
    while (j < myDoubles.Length)
    {
    double myDoubles1 = myDoubles[j];
    j++;
    double myDoubles2 = myDoubles[j];
    j++;
    double myDoubles3 = myDoubles[j];
    j++;
    double myDoubles4 = myDoubles[j];
    j++;
    double myDoubles5 = myDoubles[j];
    j++;

    while (myDoubles1 < myDoubles2 && myDoubles1 < myDoubles3 && myDoubles1 < myDoubles4 && myDoubles1 < myDoubles5)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("myDoubles[1] is the lowest");
      break;
    }
    while (myDoubles2 < myDoubles1 && myDoubles2 < myDoubles3 && myDoubles2 < myDoubles4 && myDoubles2 < myDoubles5)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("myDoubles[2] is the lowest");
      break;
    }
    while (myDoubles3 < myDoubles1 && myDoubles3 < myDoubles2 && myDoubles3 < myDoubles4 && myDoubles3 < myDoubles5)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("myDoubles[3] is the lowest");
      break;
    }
    while (myDoubles4 < myDoubles1 && myDoubles4 < myDoubles2 && myDoubles4 < myDoubles3 && myDoubles4 < myDoubles5)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("myDoubles[4] is the lowest");
      break;
    }
    while (myDoubles5 < myDoubles1 && myDoubles5 < myDoubles2 && myDoubles5 < myDoubles3 && myDoubles5 < myDoubles4)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("myDoubles[5] is the lowest");
      break;
    }
```

Comment: Well just typing into google what you want should give you the code...although it is really good that you made an attempt.

Comment: Hint: you're in a loop but _doing the same thing 5 times_.  You don;t need 5 different variables, you need to compare the current value with the lowest value _so far_.

Comment: Definitely not what I would expect to get back if I was the instructor...

Comment: Try doing this with a `for` or `foreach` loop.  Hint: you'll need to declare a variable before the loop.

Comment: While that code is bizarre, you need to be more clear about what you are asking. See [Why is "Can Someone Help Me" not an "actual" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237) More specifically, an answer right now would *be* the code, so can you clarify what is confusing you?

Comment: I think he's look for some other way for me to accomplish this. I don't think I'm actually showing how to properly use iteration to solve this. It's more like I'm manipulating the loops to act more like an if than decision process.

Comment: Start with this: Write a `for` loop that **iterates** over the array and outputs each element to the screen.  You should only be accessing ONE element of the array per iteration of the loop.

Comment: There is no way for SO community to know what your instructor is looking for. In current state the question is very unclear as you don't seem to know what actually should be done and hence can't convey this knowledge in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this which fully satisfied the teacher's requirements. Thank you Greg and Ludovic for your examples. You were a very big help in figuring out the answer to this assignment!

```
 int j = 0;
 double min = 0; 
 for (int i = 0; i < myDoubles.Length; i++)
  {
    if (i == 0)
    {
      min = myDoubles[i];
    }
    else if (min > myDoubles[i])
    {
      min = myDoubles[i];
      j = i;
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("myDoubles[{0}] = {1} is the lowest value in the array", j, min);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double minValue(double[] myDoubles){
    double min = Double.MaxValue;
    for(int i=0; i<myDoubles.Length; i++)
    {
        if(myDoubles[i]<min)
            min = myDoubles[i];
    }
    return min;
}
```

You need to set you `min` variable to the `MaxValue` because you don't know what the maximum value will be. For example if your user give you 1000 has the min value but you set the variable to 0 the final min value will be 0, witch is obviously wrong !

Comment: Since he is 'not asking for the solution' (quote from OP) this is not an 'answer'. But actually his question is indeed not very clear. So I guess this might be ... the best bet.

Comment: @Matmarbon I know but it may help him to understand how to do it :)

Comment: Ludovic, I think you have helped me a lot here. Though, I can't use the MaxValue attribute, I believe I can use other means of finding it, thank you.

Comment: @Michael i think Greg have given a really good answer with the nullable variable have a look at it

Comment: There seem to be a lot of arbitrary and unusual requirements for how this needs to be implemented.

Comment: Instead of using an initial min/max value to check against, set it to the first element of the array.  Now start iterating at element 1 instead of 0...

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you simply do the following: *This is to find the maximum*.

```
public static double? FindMaximum(double[] container)
{
     double? max = null;
     foreach(var content in contaner)
         if(content > max || max == null)
              max = content as double;

     return max;
}
```

This approach is quite simple, you iterate through each item in your array.  Then compare the maximum to the content, if it is higher then the previous value it will modify the variable.  Then returns the highest value out of your array.

It isn't one of the ideal approaches but one solution.

Comment: He is asking for the min value

Comment: Even for the max value your solution doesn't works. If the max value is inferior to 0

Comment: @Ludovic I understand he is looking for the minimum, I gave another approach so I'm not doing his work.  If `max` is less than your array item, it will modify.  Fixed the decimal approach, I was attempting to create a simple solution not a specific since I'm unaware of his constraints.

Comment: Ok but can you specify that you are doing the inverse of what he want? and i will remove my downvote ;)

Comment: Done, you may want to clarify why you call `maxValue` on your double before it hits your loop so he understands.

Comment: Have you run this code?  You're comparing "content" against "max", which is initially null; therefore [the comparison always returns false](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) and "max" never gets set: "When you perform comparisons with nullable types, if the value of one of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons evaluate to false except for != (not equal).".  Change your if statement to: `if (!max.HasValue || content > max) max = content;`.  The return type needs to be changed or return just the value of "max", not "max" itself.